# Can two different sets of prime numbers sum up to the same value

Tags: prime-numbers

Assume

1. A is a set of prime numbers with no duplicate elements
2. B is a set of prime numbers with no duplicate elements
3. A is not equal to B
4. Cardinality of A is equal to cardinality of B

Is it possible for sum of the elements of A to be equal to sum of the elements of B?

Comment: $\{5,13\},\{7,11\}$?

Comment: Damn:(. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try for example $3+13 = 5+11$. There are many other solutions.